# Which approach limits memory usage: SqlReader.GetBytes or SqlReader.GetStream for large blobs?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader

I want to determine how to limit the memory usage inside a job which retrieves a blob from a local database and transfers it to a third party web service via chunks.

Using SqlDataReader, I appear to have two options:

1. Create a method that uses GetBytes with an offset to retrieve part of a blob returning a byte[]. The caller of the method would then be responsible for making a web request to transfer this chunk.
2. Create a method that uses GetStream and make multiple requests to ReadAsync to fill up a byte[] buffer, making a web request with this buffer until the document has been transferred.

I have a preference for option 1, because it limits the responsibility of the method, however if I call GetBytes with an offset, will it load the entire offset into memory or is sql server capable of just returning the small chunk requested?
If I use option 2, then the method will have two responsibilities, loading a chunk from the database and making web requests to store the document elsewhere.

```cs
// option 1
public async Task<Tuple<int, byte[]>> GetDocumentChunk(int documentId, int offset, int maxChunkSize)
{
    var buffer = new byte[maxChunkSize];

    string sql = "SELECT Data FROM Document WHERE Id = @Id";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", documentId);

            using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
            {
                if (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    int bytesRead = (int)reader.GetBytes(0, offset, buffer, 0, maxChunkSize);
                    return new Tuple<int, byte[]>(bytesRead, buffer);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return new Tuple<int, byte[]>(0, buffer);
}

//option 2
public async Task<CallResult> TransferDocument(int documentId, int maxChunkSize)
{
    var buffer = new byte[maxChunkSize];

    string sql = "SELECT Data FROM Document WHERE Id = @Id";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", documentId);

            using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
            {
                using (Stream uploadDataStream = reader.GetStream(0))
                {
                    CallResult callResult;
                    int bytesRead;
                    do
                    {
                        bytesRead = await uploadDataStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, maxChunkSize);
                        callResult = await MyWebRequest(documentId, buffer, bytesRead);
                        if (callResult != CallResult.Success)
                        {
                            return callResult;
                        }
                    } while (bytesRead > 0);

                    return callResult;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sqlclient-streaming-support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With option 1 you'll make many requests to the source to get the data and `GetBytes` does not 'search' stream on the SQL server (and I'll surprise if it does), that will be a very inefficient solution.

### IAsyncEnumerable

With option 2 you get the stream and process it as on-demand, so you'll make a single DB request and will gain all benefits from asynchronous I/O.

With `C# 8` [IAsyncEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerable-1?view=netstandard-2.1) will fit your problem perfectly, but it is in the `Preview` stage so far.

### CopyToAsync

If you can get a stream where you need to upload content to, then you can use [CopyToAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copytoasync?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Stream_CopyToAsync_System_IO_Stream_System_Int32_). But I assume that each chunk will be uploaded in the individual request. If so, you may introduce a component which will *quack* like a `Stream` but will actually upload content to the website when [DB stream calls CopyToAsync()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,173) on it:

```
class WebSiteChunkUploader : Stream
{
     private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
     public override bool CanWrite => true;
     public override bool CanRead => false;

     public override async Task WriteAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>

         await _client.PostAsync("localhost", new ByteArrayContent(buffer,offset, count));
}
```

### Old Good IEnumerable

Unfortunately you cannot mix `yield return` of `IEnumerable` with `async/await`. But if you decide to read stream with a blocking api, eg `Read`, then you can rewrite it with old good `yield return`:

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<byte[],int>> TransferDocument(int documentId, int maxChunkSize)
{
    string sql = "SELECT Data FROM Document WHERE Id = @Id";
    var buffer = new byte[maxChunkSize];
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", documentId);
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
            using (Stream uploadDataStream = reader.GetStream(0))
            {
                while(var bytesRead = uploadDataStream.Read(buffer, 0, maxChunkSize)) > 0)
                   yield return Tuple(buffer, bytesRead);
            }
        }
    }
}

...
async Task DoMyTransfer() 
{
  foreach(var buffer in TransferDocument(1, 10000)) {
    await moveBytes(buffer)
  }
}
```

In this case you won't have async IO with DB and fancy `Tasks`, but I suppose you'll need to throttle this upload operation anyway to do not overload DB with the connections.